# Describe image of unit circle $|z| = 1$ under $ f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-\alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have the following Möbius transformation:
$$
f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z-\alpha} \quad \alpha \neq -1
$$
And I have to describe the image of the unit circle ($|z| = 1$).

I can use symmetries in Riemann sphere and I don't have to do it analytically. So I found a solution for $ |\alpha| = 1 $ (just a line).

But I can't find the center and the radius of the circle for $ |\alpha| \neq 1 $. How to use symmetry for circles?

Thank you!

Comment: My strategy is this: I know that the image is either a circle or a line. Take three points on the unit circle, say $\pm1$ and $i$, and see where they go. There’s only one circle/line that contains the three image points; there you are. I’m not sure it profiteth you to specify the center and the radius: there may be other better modes of specification.

Comment: @Lubin, thanks, this is useful. But I think my question is a little bit unclear. I need the center and the radius with respect to alpha.

Comment: If $|\alpha| \neq 1$, take the point $\alpha$ and find its symmetric point wrt the unit circle. Then consider the images of those two points. To find the radius, use $f(-1) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good method for such questions is to perform the transformation in easy steps. Viz:

Subtract $\alpha$, invert, multiply by $\alpha +1$, add $1$.

The only 'difficult' step is the second of these. The circle before that stage is $(z+\alpha)(z^*+\alpha^*)=1$. Let $w=\frac{1}{z}$, then $(\frac{1}{w}+\alpha)(\frac{1}{w^*}+\alpha^*)=1$ and so $(\alpha w+1)(\alpha^*w^*+1)=ww^*$.

Put this in the form $(\alpha \alpha^*-1)ww^* +\alpha^*w^*+\alpha w+1=0$. This gives us the centre and radius of the circle. For example, the centre is at $-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha \alpha^*-1}$.

The rest of the transformation is now straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually I did it in another way. During my previous attempts I got something like you $ (|\alpha|^2 - 1) ww^* + \dots w + \dots w^* + \dots = 0 $. But I didn't know that I can stop here and consider it as an equation of a circle. So now I came up with a solution after extracting center and radius from this equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w = f(z)=\frac{z+1}{z-\alpha} $. Then $z(w-1) = \alpha w +1$. Given $|z|=1$, we have

$$|w-1|^2 = |\alpha w +1|^2\implies (w-1)(\bar{w}-1)=(\alpha w +1)(\bar{\alpha}\bar{ w} +1)$$

Rearrange,

$$(1-|\alpha^2|)|w|^2 -2Re[(1+\alpha)w] = 0$$

and express it in the form,

$$|w|^2 - 2Re\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}w\right)
+\bigg|\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}\bigg|^2=\bigg|\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}\bigg|^2$$

or, explicitly, in the form of a circle,

$$\bigg|w-\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}\bigg|^2=\bigg|\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}\bigg|^2$$

Thus, the center of the circle is $\frac{1+\alpha}{1-|\alpha^2|}$ and its radius is $\frac{|1+\alpha|}{1-|\alpha^2|}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to expand upon what Lubin said in a comment to give a hint.

Since we have a  Möbius transformation, we know that the unit circle must be mapped to either a line or a circle. Let's map three points from the unit circle.

First notice that:

$$
f(z) = \dfrac{z+1}{z-\alpha} = z + \dfrac{1}{z} - \alpha
$$

So we have:

$$
f(1) = 2-\alpha\\
f(-1) = -\alpha-2\\
f(i) = -\alpha
$$

Let's write $\alpha = x+iy$, with $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

So we could also write our three points as:

$$
f(1) = (-x+2)-iy\\
f(-1) = (-x-2)-iy\\
f(i) = -x-iy
$$

Now you just need to write the equation of the line/circle defined by these three points.